# Django - negative query in one-to-many relationship

Tags: django, django-queryset

Given these models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='posts')

class Comment(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, related_name='comments')
    body_text = models.TextField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Given a profile, **I want to find all of the blog posts created by that profile, where there are either no comments, or only the creator of the post has commented.**

For example:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(id={id})
profile.posts.exclude(~Q(comments__created_by=profile))
```

I thought .exclude(~Q(comments__created_by=profile) would exclude all posts where a comment exists that has been created by someone other than the profile, but that's not working out. (It is finding posts where the created_by is null, and also posts where the profile has commented along with other users - which I'm trying to exclude from the set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is this:

```
comments_by_others_in_profile_posts = Comment.objects \
    .filter(blog__created_by=profile) \
    .exclude(created_by=profile)

profile.posts.exclude(comments=comments_by_others_in_profile_posts)
```

You can also try it like this (*i believe this way it can be a little bit faster, but need to see the queries EXPLAIN output*):

```
profile.posts.exclude(id__in=comments_by_others_in_profile_posts.values_list('blog', flat=True))
```

Comment: Thanks @Todor. You have a typo in your answer. I think you meant: `profile.posts.exclude(comments__in=comments_by_others_in_profile_posts)`  --- but it does work! Thank you!

Comment: You welcome ;) PS. It's not a typo, its the same as `__in` try it :))

Comment: I get a  database error,  1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row' when I try without the `__in`. Using MySQL and Django 1.4. Maybe it works under a different env. Regardless, good answer!

Answer (score 0):

Well you were almost there, just need to include the conditions from your instincts. A good way to go about this is to use the django shell and a bunch of test data that matches your permutations. For more complex queries, its a good idea to write a unit test first.

```
profile.posts.filter(Q(comments__isnull=True)|~Q(comments__created_by=profile, comments__created_by__isnull=False))
```

Comment: Thanks ESPmorph. I believe the query you wrote will get every BlogPost, written by the profile, that either has no comments (good!), or at least one comment written by a profile other than the BlogPost profile (bad!). I was looking for BlogPosts written by the profile, with no comments, or comments only by the profile. In other words, exclude any post containing a comment from another profile. If you can fix your query, I'd be curious to see how!